# Python barcode: cannot open resource

Tags: python, barcode, py2exe

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I'm trying to make an application with a module **python barcode**
when I compiled it raw it working well but when I tried to turn it into an exe (using autopytoexe) this gives me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sad.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "site-packages\barcode\base.py", line 68, in save
  File "site-packages\barcode\ean.py", line 122, in render
  File "site-packages\barcode\base.py", line 111, in render
  File "site-packages\barcode\writer.py", line 226, in render
  File "site-packages\barcode\writer.py", line 356, in _paint_text
  File "site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 648, in truetype
  File "site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 645, in freetype
  File "site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 193, in __init__
OSError: cannot open resource
```

This is the code that I'm currently running

```
import barcode
import os.path
import os
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

number = "0000000000000"
prodname = "Chicken Biryani"
directory = './Barcodes/'
a = barcode.get_barcode_class('ean13')
img_bar = a(number, writer = ImageWriter())
if not os.path.isdir(directory):
    os.mkdir(directory)
img_bar.save("Barcodes\\"+prodname)
img = Image.open("Barcodes\\"+prodname+'.png')
fnt = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf",50)
d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
d.text((80,190), prodname, font=fnt, fill=(0,0,0))
img.save("Barcodes\\"+prodname+'.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

This library is using `DejaVuSansMono` font. You have to paste that font into folder which contains the `.exe` file.